# dd: failed to open ‘/disk1/boot1.img’: Structure needs cleaning

Tags: hard-drive, xfs, corruption, dd

Executing this Command :

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/disk1/boot1.img
```

I got this Error :

```
dd: failed to open ‘/disk1/boot1.img’: Structure needs cleaning
```

I tried that Command on my centos machine and got that Error. How do I fix that Error? It's xfs file system. Should I do xfs_repair on disk1 by unmounting it?

Answer (score 0):

If your `/dsik1/` mounted on `/dev/sda1` It's normal error. You can't `dd` a disk on itelf.

Comment: What led you to that conclusion? `dd` is reading raw data and writing it to a file. It has no idea that the file is located on the same physical device. In fact, this operation is/was fairly common to extract the boot block from a disk. The `open` call also will not report this error just because of being on the same device. The Op will get a different failure when the file system runs out of space.